# MVC шаблон в библиотеке

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

При дроблении монолита на модули, возникло дублирование шаблонов.
Хочется вынести общий шаблон сайта в библиотеку в файл _ViewStart.cshtml, затем использовать его во всех проектах. (Все проекты наследуют библиотеку где есть _ViewStart). Правильное ли это решение или есть другой способ?

Comment: Не совсем понятно что вы имеете в виду под дроблением монолита на модули. Вы имеет в виду, что в едином Solution, вы выделяете отдельные проекты? То есть создаете N-Tier(многослойную) архитектуру? Если да,  то у вас остается такой же монолит, и в нем можно создать такую библиотеку. Но если вы дробите Монолит, на Микросервисы, тогда так не получится. Но при дроблении на микросервисы, все что связано с фронтендом, как правило остается в одном проекте, а остальной бекенд, выносится в независимые WEB-API.

Comment: Я хочу разделить большой проект на модули., как есть. Принцип разделения будет основан на Route. Воспользовался статьей по многоразовому использованию пользовательского интерфейса.

Comment: Прочел ответ, понял. Спасибо, интересно.

Answer (score 1):

Создание многоразового пользовательского интерфейса с помощью проекта библиотеки классов Razor в ASP.NET Core
https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/aspnet/core/razor-pages/ui-class?view=aspnetcore-3.1